# Triangulation of clusters of points

Tags: geometry, triangulation, clustering

I am trying to solve a triangulation problem, but I am not really sure what is the best way to tackle it.

I have a series of points $P$ in an $n$-dimensional space. These points are clustered in $k$ clusters $P_1, P_2, ..., P_k$ and then projected onto a 2-dimensional space.

I would now like to triangulate this plane with $k$ triangles, maximizing the number of points of the same cluster falling into the same triangle.

An *easy* example would be:
[image: example of triangulation]

In this case the points are well-clustered in the 2-dimensional space, but this may or may not be the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Genetic algorithm?  :-)  Something like:  http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/  ?  Research on Voroni diagrams or Delaunay triangulation are the closest branches of math I can think of, but I don't think there are deterministic solutions, and they don't precisely fit your issue.  Very interesting, though.